# Error propagation in CBC mode

Tags: cbc, modes-of-operation, error-propagation

Going through the wiki for [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Error_propagation) I see that the section error propagation says that an error in one block in the ciphertext in CBC mode only impacts two blocks. I do not quite get that. If the second plaintext block is decrypted wrong, then why would it not impact the third block?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In CBC mode the decryption equation is $P_i = D_k(C_i) \oplus C_{i-1}$. If you received a corrupted $C_i$, $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$ will be decrypted wrong, but $P_{i+2}$ no longer depends on $C_i$ and will be correct.

Comment: Oops.. the xor is done with the plaintext and NOT the cipher text. One of those dumb moments. Thanks.