# Error propagation in CBC

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, openssl, error-propagation

I am doing an error propagation experiment with the CBC mode.I have encrypted a 100 byte text file with openssl. I made the 55th bytes of my encrypted file corrupted.As per theory the corresponding block of 49-64 bytes and the subsequent block of 65-80 bytes should be affected on decryption.But I am only getting the 49-63 bytes impacted in the result.Any help to let me understand this contradiction will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does error propagation in CBC mode encryption affect two blocks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72822/why-does-error-propagation-in-cbc-mode-encryption-affect-two-blocks). Because you modified the ciphertext after the encryption. During decryption ciphertext effects only at most two blocks.

Comment: Well, not exactly.Instead of two I am getting error propagated only in one block.

Comment: Did you try with different plaintext?

Comment: If you are using one-origin (which most programmers don't) _all_ of block 49-64 should be changed but only _one byte_ in the next block, namely byte 71.

Comment: @Aneek I think this answer indicates your missing point as dave_thompson said. [https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66085/18298](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66085/bit-flipping-attack-on-cbc-mode/66086#66086)

Comment: So, has this problem been solved? Can you now see that only one byte has changed value in the second block affected?